# how to change the master page icon in the master interface details and center position title page on toolbar?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I wish I could change the icon of the master page and on the toolbar and center the title of the different pages on the toolbar, but I can't understand how to do it, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

it's so simple.

if you wanted to change icon of toolbar than you can simply update your icon like this, `<MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <ContentPage x:Name="mstr" Icon="top_menu_icon" Title="Menu"> </ContentPage>
 </MasterDetailPage.Master>`

if you wanted to change toolbar text to center than it's easier now, you can customize your toolbar in ContentPage now like,

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
     <Label Text="Hello Bk" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="White"/>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: can I make the title label only see on android? @KurnalBagadia

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change toolbar text to center and make the title label only see on android, you can try the following code:

in XAML

```
 <NavigationPage.TitleView VerticalOptions="Center" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center" >            
<Label Text="Hello Bk"  TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center" >
  <Label.IsVisible>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Boolean"
                  iOS="true"
                  Android="true"/>
  </Label.IsVisible>  
</Label>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

The effect in ios is like this:

[image]

Comment: I wish I could have the title without a label displayed on iOS so I don't see anything now, is there a way?

Comment: when you set the value in ios to `false`(`iOS="false"`) ,  Is the code useless?

Comment: I gave up, I keep the label, but it doesn't center with the toolbar and I don't understand why, on iphone it is moved too much by the clock that is centered

Comment: @FrancescoRusso You can try to add VerticalOptions="Center" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center", I have updated the answer, you can check it.